# getActionBar() returning null

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need my actionbar to be ready before setContentView because it is used by the navDrawerFragment but at this point:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    Log.d("", getActionBar().toString());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
}
```

It is returning null

My theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:positiveButtonText">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>
```

and the declaration at manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".controller.activity.BaseActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Set theme for activity like android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your `BaseActivity` must `extends` from `ActionBarActivity` and not `Activity`

   `public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {`
2. Use `getSupportActionBar();` to get the ***ActionBar***

Comment: You are right, but why? Since my min sdk is 17, shouldn't I be able to just extend Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is either one of these two things, or both. At least they should be, unless I'm insane..

Either the problem is that you are calling

```
getActionBar()
```

before you set the contentView
So change it to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
    Log.d("", getActionBar().toString());
}
```

**OR**
It is that you need to call

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

Try both and tell me which works!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the support library (AppCompat), so you have to call `getSupportActionBar()`